# How to set 'mouseover' event for per gridview row?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm using ASP.NET (C#). I have designed a gridview and loaded data from database (SQL Server). That's ok.

Here is advanced requirement:
-> The database contains a field that it cannot be showed while debugging. Because I had wrote:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="course_group" HeaderText="Course group" SortExpression="course_group" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hidden" ItemStyle-CssClass="hidden" />
```

In css:

```
.hidden
{
display: none;
}
```

-> Now, I wanna get the value of **course_group** and set it into **gridview row** as a **"Tooltip"**. Like this:

```
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com" title="I'm a tooltip">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>
```

I know the way to write a **link tooltip**, but not for **gridview row tooltip**.

I think it's difficult, because you might want to many different tooltip text for all gridview rows

Is there anyway to do that?
Can you give me any C# code behind solution (**mouseover** event) or CSS/Javascript code solution (**hover** event)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.ToolTip = (e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView)["Description"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Reference [Here](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-GridView-Row-details-on-Cell-MouseOver-using-jQuery-ToolTip-Plugin-in-ASPNet.aspx)